# How to change the background of a div using the select tag and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found an answer to my question here but it really doesn't work for me. I am very new to programming and quite not yet familiar using javascript. Sad to say, I've been trying to do this for quite a while.

What I want to do is to change the background of a div whenever I change the option in a select tag. Here's my .JSP code

```
Add Ons Type:
<select id="addOnsType" name="addOnsType" onchange="changePicture()">
    <option selected disabled> select add ons</option>
    <c:forEach var="addOnsType" items="${addOnsType}">
        <option value="${addOnsType.addOnsTypeId}"> ${addOnsType.description} </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>

<div id="PictureDiv" style="height: 58px; width: 344px">
</div>
```

The addOnsTypeId has values of 1, 2 and 3.

While my javascript is written as (I've used what I saw in here)

```
function changePicture() {

    var PictureDivBG = document.getElementById("PictureDiv");
    var addOnsTypeSelected = document.getElementById("addOnsType");

    if (addOnsTypeSelected.val() == 1) {
        PictureDivBG.style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/cartoon1.jpg')";
    } else if (addOnsTypeSelected.val() == 2) {
        PictureDivBG.style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/cartoon2.jpg')";
    } else if (addOnsTypeSelected.val() == 3) {
        PictureDivBG.style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/cartoon3.jpg')";
    }

};
```

Any help/hints/answers would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Follow up newbie question: I'm quite confused about javascript and jQuery, what's the difference?

Comment: Jquery is a library that is written in javascript which allows for easier / more reliable coding for web-based JavaScript. Think of it as a toolkit for making js easier to develop.

Comment: thanks for the info! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addOnsTypeSelected` is a dom element reference, it doesn't have the `val()` function, which is provided by jQuery.

You can get the jQuery object for those element using the id selector and get the value

```
function changePicture() {
  var addOnsTypeSelected = $("#addOnsType").val(),
    backgroundImage;

  if (addOnsTypeSelected == 1) {
    backgroundImage = "url('../images/cartoon1.jpg')";
  } else if (addOnsTypeSelected == 2) {
    backgroundImage = "url('../images/cartoon2.jpg')";
  } else if (addOnsTypeSelected == 3) {
    backgroundImage = "url('../images/cartoon3.jpg')";
  }
  $('#PictureDiv').css('background-image', backgroundImage);

};
```

But using jQuery event handlers, you can

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var imgs = {
    1: 'url(//placehold.it/64/ff0000)',
    2: 'url(//placehold.it/64/00ff00)',
    3: 'url(//placehold.it/64/0000ff)'
  }
  $('#addOnsType').change(function() {
    $('#PictureDiv').css('background-image', imgs[$(this).val()] || 'none');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Add Ons Type:
<select id="addOnsType" name="addOnsType">
  <option selected disabled>select add ons</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>

<div id="PictureDiv" style="height: 58px; width: 344px">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try the first one since I've used an id selector last time and then explore the second one. :)